# Confused about add_library()

Tags: cmake

I am currently developing a library that will hopefully help students render basic 2D graphics very easily with c++. The problem is the way I am building it. Here is a working version:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8 )

project( HWAPI )

set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11 )

find_package( SDL2 REQUIRED )

include_directories( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/ )
include_directories( ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR} )

set( SRC_FILES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/basic_example.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/window.hpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/window.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/color.hpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/color.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/vec2.hpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/vec2.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/hwapi.hpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/hwapi.cpp
    )

add_executable( example ${SRC_FILES} )

target_link_libraries( example ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} )
```

The executable is created successfully and the application works as expected. But I would like to build this as a library and simply link it to the main program so that I can easily create a custom template in codeblocks(what my school is using). Here is what I have done so far:

```
    cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8 )

    project( HWAPI )

    set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11 )

    find_package( SDL2 REQUIRED )

    include_directories( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/ )
    include_directories( ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR} )

    set( SRC_FILES
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/window.hpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/window.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/color.hpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/color.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/vec2.hpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/vec2.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/hwapi.hpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/hwapi.cpp
        )

    add_library( HW_LIB ${SRC_FILES} )

    target_link_libraries( HW_LIB ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} )

    add_executable( basic_example 
           ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/basic_example.cpp 
                  )
    target_link_libraries( basic_example ${HW_LIB} )
```

Running make gives the following error(s):

```
CMakeFiles/basic_example.dir/tests/basic_example.cpp.o: In function `main':
basic_example.cpp:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `hw::color::color(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)'
basic_example.cpp:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `dummy_api::point(int, int, hw::color const&)'
basic_example.cpp:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `hw::color::color(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)'
basic_example.cpp:(.text+0xac): undefined reference to `dummy_api::line(int, int, int, int, hw::color const&)'
basic_example.cpp:(.text+0xcd): undefined reference to `hw::color::color(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)'
basic_example.cpp:(.text+0xfb): undefined reference to `dummy_api::outline_triangle(int, int, int, int, int, int, hw::color const&)'
basic_example.cpp:(.text+0x13b): undefined reference to `dummy_api::rectangle(int, int, int, int, hw::color const&)'
basic_example.cpp:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to `dummy_api::outline_rectangle(int, int, int, int, hw::color const&)'
basic_example.cpp:(.text+0x1b5): undefined reference to `dummy_api::draw(std::function<void ()>, std::function<void ()>)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [basic_example] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/basic_example.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The example which I want to run simply calls a few functions provided by the library, nothing more. Why can't I create the library as expected? I am sure there is something about add_library that I do not understand(even though I've spent many hours looking at the documentation). Other related posts suggest that something is wrong in my implementation(eg. multiple definitions of a function) but that is not the case since I can perfectly run the app.

Comment: The `target_link_libraries` should use `HW_LIB` not `${HW_LIB}`, which is an empty variable, right?

Comment: All this time looking at the documentation and not seeing the difference...Thank you so much!

Comment: @compor Please consider to transfer your comment into an answer, so AlexandruIca can accept it to mark this question solved.

Comment: @StanleyF. will do, although it's a bit trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
target_link_libraries(basic_example ${HW_LIB})
```

should be

```
target_link_libraries(basic_example HW_LIB)
```

`HW_LIB` is the name of the target, using `${HW_LIB}` is an undeclared variable which results in evaluating in nothing.

Lastly, have a look at the doc for [variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variables) and the wee more advanced topic of [variable references](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variable-references).